# How to use iconsax CSS3 icons?

Tags: html, css, icons, web-deployment

I have downloaded a package of free icons for CSS3 from https://www.iconsax.io . But I couldn't find that how to use them. Can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On iconsax.io, You can just right click on an icon you want to use and download it in svg format and then you can link it to your html file using img tag or open the image with a text/code editor and copy paste the code directly inside an

```
  <svg> ... </svg> tag
```

**Edit:**

Since your question was that you've already downloaded the package and you don't know how to use it, it's very easy. You just need to copy paste that package in the same folder that has your web development files and inside html, you can use an img tag to link them like this:

```
 <img src="packages/icon.svg"></img>
```

Or as I said earlier you can view the icon's svg code and use it in html file under svg tag.

Comment: Isn't the CSS file for fontawesome like usage like <i class="isax-video></i> ? If so, where can I find a List of all icons with their classes?

Comment: @Weissvonnix You can find all the fontawesome icons here: https://fontawesome.com/search